# Sobrecargando el operador =

Tags: c++

estoy realizando la sobrecarga del operador = para un tipo de datos Racional.
Es decir, para que esto funcione con el tipo Racional:

```
res = p;
```

Según el libro que estoy siguiendo, me dice que lo realice con el operador = como función miembro (método) y:

> 1. Que reciba un tipo por referencia.
> 2. Que cree yo un objeto con el constructor de copia pasándole como parámetro el objeto recibido en dicha función.
> 3. Que intercambie ese objeto creado por el *this.
> 4. Que devuelva *this.

Implementándolo, y funcionando no hay problemas (funciona perfectamente) con la versión que he hecho, que sería esta (corregidme si no está bien):

```
Racional& Racional::operator=(const Racional& der)
{
  Racional auxiliar(der);
  this->numerador = auxiliar.obtenerNumerador();
  this->denominador = auxiliar.obtenerDenominador();
  return *this;
}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente. ¿Por qué tengo que crear un objeto auxiliar si puedo directamente hacer:

```
Racional& Racional::operator=(const Racional& der)
{
  this->numerador = der.obtenerNumerador();
  this->denominador = der.obtenerDenominador();
  return *this;
}
```

Muchas gracias por todo compañeros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ¿Por qué tengo que crear un objeto auxiliar?

En mi opinión la pregunta debería ser "*¿Por qué debo adoptar una solución concreta en este caso concreto?*".

En el operador de asignación (y su gemelo maligno, el operador de movimiento) no existe una sola solución o patrón válido siempre, cada tipo de datos puede requerir una solución diferente.

#### El modismo de copia-intercambio.

Como bien has comentado, en el caso concreto de tu tipo `Racional` no tienes necesidad alguna de un objeto auxiliar. Es posible que se mencione el auxiliar como parte del modismo de copia-intercambio (*copy swap idiom* en inglés).

El modismo de copia-intercambio consiste en delegar la funcionalidad de asignación de nuevos valores en el constructor de copia, mediante la creación de una copia local de los datos que después será intercambiada con los datos actuales; seguidamente el objeto temporal (que contiene los datos antiguos) se destruye. Es precisamente el modismo que ha usado [Trauma en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/137361/2742):

```
Racional& Racional::operator=( const Racional &der ) {
    Racional tmp( der );     // Copiamos el Racional recibido.
    std::swap( *this, tmp ); // Intercambiamos con el Racional presente.

    return *this; // Devolvemos el Racional presente, por si queremos encadenar operaciones.
} // El auxiliar se destruye.
```

#### ¿Es necesario el auxiliar?.

El modismo de copia-intercambio usa un auxiliar para asegurar que se llama el destructor del objeto para los datos que están siendo descartados; esto es relevante en los casos en que el objeto maneje recursos:

```
struct Int {
    int *i{nullptr};
    Int(const Int &) = default;
    ~Int() {
        delete i;
    }
    Int &operator =(const Int &i) {
        Int tmp(i);
        std::swap(*this, tmp);

        return *this; // delete i sera llamado.
    }
};
```

Si en el ejemplo anterior el operador de asignación hubiese sido este:

```
Int &operator =(const Int &i) {
    this->i = i;
}
```

Perderíamos el puntero `i` original, provocando una fuga de memoria. Pero no es tu caso, tu clase `Racional` no maneja recursos por lo que no necesitas usar el modismo copia-intercambio.

#### Conclusión.

C++ permite sobrecargar operadores para que podamos hacernos cargo de tareas especiales que un objeto pueda requerir al ser operado; esta personalización del comportamiento es especial en cada caso y aunque existen determinados modismos no debemos utilizarlos sin pensar si se ajustan las necesidades concretas de cada caso.

En tu caso, tu duda es relevante y correcta; la respuesta es: no necesitas el temporal... pero NO consideres esta respuesta grabada en piedra, en otras situaciones la respuesta podría ser otra.

Comment: Te ha faltado indicar que como norma general no es necesario implementar el operador de asignación

Comment: Y evitar la auto-asignación >_<

Comment: Entre otras cosas... aunque si alguien hace una autoasignación es casi más un fallo suyo que otra cosa

Comment: Ampliaré la respuesta más adelante, se acaba mi jornada de hoy d(n_n)

Comment: ... yo por ejemplo no creo que el código tenga que estar preparado para luchar contra la estupidez humana (sin ánimo de insultar a nadie)... añade un sobrecoste al desarrollo y al mantenimiento que normalmente no va a ningún sitio.

Comment: Ok. pasa buen fin de semana

Comment: Genial respuesta @Paula_plus_plus Ahora a seguir practicando, ya creo que lo logro entender. Por supuesto, que tengas un gran fin de semana, te lo mereces jejeje